# Accessing any folder from a compiled MATLAB application

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I am developing a windows stand alone application in MATLAB 2012b .

In the code I am writing some files in two folders images and dump which are both accessible to the user. I want those two folders to be in the same folder as the final executable. I can create those folders manually. However, when I run the compiled application, it does not seem to access those folders. For example, the following line of code works perfectly when run from inside MATLAB,

```
save(fullfile('./images/camp.mat'),'camp','-v7.3');
```

however it does not seem to work in GUI as it seems to stop working at that point only and nothing is created in the images folder.

I have searched through the internet and found things like ctfroot() and MCR_ROOT etc but I am not able to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean "it does not seem to work in GUI"?

Comment: Make sure your directory called /images/ exists wherever the executable is located before you try to save to it. Also, an absolute path might be more robust instead of using `./images` to go up one directory. There are several functions to determine where the executable was saved/where it will run.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear, as a question was asked in the comments, but no clarifications were forthcoming.